# Computer will not restart on it's own after install of 14.10

Tags: 14.10

I installed 14.10 on a computer that had a clean formatted HD in it. The install went good, no errors. Got to the end, said you need to restart your computer so I clicked on restart and that is all the further it went. Computer just sat there and did not restart. So I manually restarted the computer and initially everything came up like I would of expected but then the mouse and keyboard were locked up so I could not navigate anywhere. Shut it down and then restarted it and all I get is a blank screen.Did I miss something during install? I did a clean install and as before the CD ejects then the computer just sits there. Power is on but no restart. Another suggestion someone else gave me was to install 14.04. Thoughts on that. Let the computer sit and the CD tray closed but the computer did not start so I shut it downs and restarted. Of course it wanted to install 14.10 again. So I went up to system and clicked on shutdown. All went well, told me to eject the media so shutdown could complete. Did that and shutdown completed. Restarted the computer and it booted, logged in but this time it got further. Got the screen and apps on the left but no mouse or keyboard control. Any ideas and thoughts on this? Getting closer but still not there. Further update. After my lasts comments the computer I am trying to get working with 14.10 just went to a gray screen. There it sits.

Answer (score 1):

This is my personal experience. You should NOT remove your DVD/Live USB as soon as the installation is complete. You should have your installation medium while rebooting. After the computer shuts down, you can remove your installation medium. This may sound illogical but this is a possible solution to your problem.

Do a fresh install again and it'll be fine.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: It's my own personal experience. I faced this issue a couple of times. I noticed that whenever the reboot button is clicked, the DVD I use to install immediately powers up and there is some data transfer that takes place.

Comment: Then you should change "This is a known issue" into "This is my personal experience". I thought it was from a bug report or something.